# plugin-development: view call another class

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin

I am trying to create a view plugin in the Eclipse environment. I need to call another class, but when I use as usual `Class cl=new Class();` it does  not work:

```
    private void makeActions() {
    action1 = new Action() {
        public void run() {
            showMessage("Action 1 executed");
            DataInterfc interface=new DataInterfc();
        }
    };
    action1.setText("Informations");
    action1.setToolTipText("Action 1 tooltip");
    action1.setImageDescriptor(PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getSharedImages().
        getImageDescriptor(ISharedImages.IMG_OBJS_INFO_TSK));
```

I get a problem in `DataInterfc interface=new DataInterfc()`. Do I need to define the class I want to callin plugin.xml or what to do exact?

Answer (score 0):

`interface` is a reserved keyword in Java you cannot use it as a variable name (see [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/_keywords.html)).

Use some other name:

```
DataInterfc interfce = new DataInterfc();
```

The `DataInterfc` class must be defined in your plugin or in a plugin that you declare in your plug-in's dependencies.

Comment: I try to change the name but the same problem

Comment: Well what is the **exact** problem - you haven't actually told us? Edit your question on put in the messages you are getting

Answer (score 0):

interfaces cannot be instantiated, that's just basic Java